# Generate PDF from JSON using XSLT - Header and Footer content should display in all the pages along with Table

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt

I have a requirement to generate PDF from JSON Objects. Am able to generate it, but i that PDF i have a table with contents to display.

So that table should have some limited rows like, per page in pdf should display 5 rows of table and remaining rows should go to next page in PDF.

Also, on each page i should display `Header` & `Footer` and remaining rows in table.

For example

Page 1:

```
    Header Content

    Table contents  
        row1
        row2
        row3
        row4
        row5

    Footer Content
```

Page 2:

```
    Header Content

    Table contents  
        row6
        row7
        row8
        row9
        row10

    Footer Content
```

Please find my XSLT code that am trying to implement the logic here

```
<table >
    <tr >
        <th Pos./Line</th>
        <th >Item Code</th>

    </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select="order">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position() mod 5" />

        <tr >
            <td ><xsl:value-of select="line_number" /></td>
            <td ><xsl:value-of select="product_code" /></td>
        </tr>

        <xsl:if test="$pos = 0">
        <table style=" page-break-after: always;">
                <tr >
                    <td >
                        Hello This is Footer <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

Am using XSL version 1.0

Comment: Which version of XSLT  do you use? And that sample does not make sense if the used output format is HTML, you can't stuff a table into another one as you have shown. It should however be possible to generate various `tbody` elements.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - am using version 1.0. Can you please give me a sample for  that `tbody` elements. Am very new to this XSL conversion